# PyCharm-Selenium после множества(~1000) ссылок намертво зависает ОС

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

Переписываю магазин для клиента и перепаршиваю товары(заголовки и прочее).

Ситуация такая - первые 900 - 1000 ссылок все парсит нормально и записывает в csv файл, после же резко зависает вся ос и спасает только ребут.

В чем дело? Как убрать лаги-зависания(происходят и на линуксе и на виндовс) и буду благодарен если посоветуете как подредактировать код в лучшую сторону

Вот он:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

urls = [
"ссылка 1",
"ссылка 2",
...,
"ссылка 20000"
]

for url in urls:
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        title = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "title"))).text
        price = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "price"))).text
        large_imgs = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".largeImg img")
        big_img = large_imgs.get_attribute("src")
        result = title + ", " + price + ", "+ big_img + "\n"
        f = open('new.csv', 'a')
        f.write(str(result))
        f.close()
    except TimeoutException:
        pass


def teardown(self):
    self.driver.close()
```

Comment: Что на счёт мониторинга: ОЗУ, температура, нагрузка на ядра? Что на счёт блокировщиков рекламы (uBlock Origin)? У меня похожий кейс работает, но с важными оговорками (может что-то вам поможет), каждые 3 URL'а у меня браузер перезагружается, потому что нужно менять настройки, которые без перезапуска не применяются. Таким методом, на старом ноуте (1,4 ГГц, 1 ОЗУ) под управлением lubuntu 18, установленной на 8Гб флешке (лет 7 ей уже) (без своп, и с ограничениями на запись), systemd unit для запуска, journalctl для мониторинга - за сутки около 5000 URL'ов, потребляя при этом не более 500Мб ОЗУ.

Comment: Так же интересуют косвенные вопросы. 
1. Магазин клиента, вероятно есть доступ к БД магазина - не проще ли скопировать из SQL данные чем скрапить их так?
2. Причём тут, PyCharm? Вы запускаете скрипт в работу из терминала PyCharm?

Comment: Компа есть 2. Первый- i5 2400 gtx 950m 8 gb и второй pentium g840 16 гб озу(как это смешно не звучало бы) и gtx 760(около). У обоих напрочь зависает все и нет доступа ни к приложения ни к ос в целом(kubuntu/windows7/windows10) и посмотреть нагрузку я не смог. Вентилятор не крутился по окончании.

Comment: Доступа к бд как ни печально нема. Pycharm'ом просто упомянул, что делаю селениумом на питоне а не на джаве, да в терминале пайчарма

Comment: Для начала, скрипт в работу запускайте не в терминале пайчама, а терминале системы. У Пайчама своя "экосистема" Питона, и она прилично тяжелее, поэтому лучше использовать системный Питон. Так же, добавьте перезагрузку браузера ну хотя-бы каждую сотню URL. Так-же не забывайте про блокировщики рекламы, я сомневаюсь, что вам нужно тратить ресурсы своего железа на обработку метрик поисковых систем, и другие сторонние скрипты. Ну и самое главное - мониторинг, логируйте жизненные показатели компьютера, что-бы знать при каких симптомах крашится система.

Comment: перезапуск каждую сотню делать как? driver.close() то закроет но как сделать что бы кажду сотню ссылок вырубало?

Comment: Когда я запускаю с терминала скрипт у меня не работают никакие расширения и он по сути дефолтный. Пытался что то сделать но не получилось. Подскажете?

Comment: делаете нумерованный цикл (enumerate), и каждую 100 делаете `driver.quit()` и заново запускаете в опцией `headless = True`. В терминале не работает, потому что вы Селениум установили только в PyCharm Питоне, а не в системном. Установите в системный Питон (рекомендую через virtualenv), но на крайний случай можно и просто в терминале `pip install -U selenium` - это для винды

Comment: все равно не подгружаются расширения(через системный cmd запустил).

Comment: about:config тоже не работает =(

Comment: Опубликуйте весь код пожалуйста

Comment: Нашел проблему! Вся озу напрочь забита фаерфоксом и hdd также на 100%

Comment: сейчас добавлю enumerate и скажу решилась ли проблема

Comment: "весь код парсера в топике"  пытался добавить enumerate но не понимаю как его сделать =(

Comment: все что получилось так это вывести (0 , 100 | 1, 200 и т.д. ) но не знаю как сделать что бы все срабатывало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оформляете инициализацию браузера в отдельную функцию:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options


def run_browser(): 
    global driver
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

Дальше нумерованный цикл:

```
for number, url in enumerate(urls):
```

Что-бы проверить, 100-й ли URL, нужно номер текущей итерации (number) поделить на 100 и узнать был ли остаток целым числом (100 поделить на 100 будет 1.0, а 101 поделить на 100 будет 1.01):

```
for number, url in enumerate(urls):
    if (number/100).is_integer():
        driver.quit()
        run_browser()
        driver.get(url)
    else:
        driver.get(url)
```

В итоге ваш минимальный код выглядит так:

```
from selenium import webdriver  #импорт библиотеки селениума
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options  # импорт библиотеки "настройки" запуска браузера

urls = [
"ссылка 1",
"ссылка 2",
...,
"ссылка 20000"
]  # ваша переменная с массивом URL


def run_browser():  # функция, в которую мы оформляем запуск браузера, для доступа в любом месте кода
    global driver
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)


run_browser()  # Первый запуск браузера с помощью оформленной функции
for number, url in enumerate(urls):  # Нумерованный цикл
    if (number/100).is_integer():  # Проверяем, если 'number' делится на 100 без остатка, значит это 100 кратный цикл
        driver.quit()  # Закрываем браузер
        run_browser()  # Запускаем браузер используя оформленную функцию
        driver.get(url)  # Переходим по текущему URL
    else:
        driver.get(url)  # Иначе, (цикл не 100 кратный) просто переходи по текущему URL
driver.quit()  # в конце работы выключаем браузер. driver.close() не закроет браузер если вкладок стало больше одной!
```

Comment: Ого, понял, большое спасибо за решение!

Comment: Если не против то спрошу, нужны ли ожидания WebDriverWait(driver, 4) при гигабитном интернете? И как все же подключить профиль, я подключил profile = FirefoxProfile("/home/tanik/.cache/mozilla/firefox/gzmf2y74.default") но мне выдало NameError: name 'FirefoxProfile' is not defined

Comment: Вам не нужны ожидания между запуском браузера и переходом на страницу. То есть Wait лишний при любом интернете, потому как в том месте где он у вас стоит, он просто удлиняет скрипт на 5 секунд. Профиль определяется так - 1. `fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile("/home...")` 2. `driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)`

Comment: То-есть все писать через driver.find_element_by_css_selector(или class_name)? Просто я сейчас тестирую и у меня получается так - первые 100 ссылок чуть ли не по 1 секунде на каждую грузятся а после того как браузер закрывается и открывается снова скорость падает до 1 ссылки в 5 секунд. hdd свободный и озу с процессором достаточно

Comment: Все необходимые елементы прогружаются и отображаются, но страницу продолжает грузится

Comment: убрал везде ожидания и вроде проблема решилась, снова благодарю :)

Comment: Отлично)) что-бы воцарила идиллия, предлагаю вам отметить ответ как ответ))

Comment: уже отметил :-)

Comment: Поставил парсить на ночь. Спарсило 700 ссылок(ровно) и выдало selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .title

Comment: Ожидания все же нужны были похоже

Comment: Иногда перед поиском элемента на странице нужно проверить загрузился или стал видимым, это явное ожидание, почитай в доках о ожиданиях в Селениуме, что-бы немножко понимать где они нужны, а где нет

Comment: Про ожидания я знаю, но также знаю, что они используются только при парсинге динамических елементов которые тянутся из DOM. Меня не то что удивило что надо добавить webdriverwait сколько то, какой метод выбрать(какой из них самый быстрый) - presence_of_element_located, visibility... или еще что?